# How is it possible to sort todos by completion?

Tags: org-mode, sorting

How is it possible to sort todos by completion?

```
* Bar [0%]
** TODO Bar1
** TODO Bar2
* Foo [100%]
** DONE Foo1
   CLOSED: [2017-06-18 So 17:51]
** DONE Foo2
   CLOSED: [2017-06-18 So 17:51]
* Foo1 [0%]
** TODO Foo1
** TODO Foo2
```

For example I might constantly add new todos and finish other todos. How is it possible to sort the todos so that the todos with `100%` will stay at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, at least with your example, but you'll need to add at least one new line before the first heading.

```lisp
(defun my-sort-entries ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (org-sort-entries nil ?f
                      (lambda ()
                        (let ((item (org-entry-get (point) "ITEM"))
                              (stats ".+\\[\\([0-9].+\\)%.+"))
                          (replace-regexp-in-string stats "\\1" item)))
                      'org-string-collate-greaterp nil t)))
```